# PTIJ: Gomel chassidim tovim- who gives us good chassidim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the first b’racha of the amida, we praise G-d for giving us good chassidim. Why are good chassidim so important to us? Which chassidim *are* good? Note that it is talking about modern-day chassidim, because it uses the present tense ‘gomel’ Verses the past tense ‘gamal’.

(Thank you [@josh k and @ezra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100455/gomel-chasadim-tovim-are-there-bad-chasadim#comment335605_100455) for the idea.)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's present tense because in the past all the Chasidim were excommunicated, so none of them were any good.

Comment: @double aa I was pointing out the difference between modern-day chassidim and Talmudic chassidim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't mean that Hashem gave us good Chassidim. It means that Hashem toes "tovim", i.e. favors, for Chassidim. That's why so many Rebbes are working miracles on a practically daily basis, while the Litvish have to suffice with the occasional "Hashgacha Pratis" story once every few weeks if they're lucky.

This is because the Chassidim steadfastly hold on to their Yiddish, speaking a different language than everyone else no matter where they live, and this tenacious clinging to one of the three things through which the Jews merited to leave Egypt brings much praise to Hashem, as we say elsewhere in our prayers:

> משובח ומפואר בלשון כל חסידיו
>
> [Hashem] is praised and glorified through the language of His Chassidim.

Comment: That translation is wonderful. Do I have your permission to relay this to a "good" Hassid whom I have known for many years and lives in my neighborhood.

Comment: @DanF Of course! Just make sure you also tell him one of the [real meanings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100479/4794)!

Comment: https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/legend-two-brothers-temple-mount/

Answer (score 3):

This is another form of *Birkat Hagomel*. One occasion when one should say Birkat Hagomel is after recovering from a serious illness esp. if it involved a hospital stay.

In the NY City area, and I assume some other areas throughout the U.S., many of the *bikur cholim* ("hospitality" rooms) are run and maintained by Hassidic groups. In NY area, Satmar runs a majority of them. Women cook and bake fresh food daily and they package and deliver food to numerous hospitals in the NY area. On numerous occasions I had to visit a relative on Friday, and I had no food at home for my family or myself for Shabbat. I was thrilled that there was a fridge with food that I could take home.

So, these are not just "good" Hassidm - they are **phenomenal** Hassidm. I honestly don't know how they manage to do this each day.

So, whether you are ill or not, the bracha refers to Hassidm such as these people who go far above and beyond to care about the ill as well as their families, and request nothing in return but a bracha and a voluntary monetary donation.